# System graph plotting

Tags: pgfplots, graphs

I want to generate the graphs with system:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal,
axis lines=middle,
axis line style={->},
tick style={color=black},
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty
]

\addplot[samples=360, domain=0:2*pi] 
({x = sin(t)*a^sin(t)+x_0}, {y = cos(t)*b^sin(t)+y_0});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This system

{ x = sin(t)*a^sin(t) + x_0

{ y = cos(t)*b^sin(t) + y_0

Answer (score 1):

You're actually not that far from the solution. `pgfplots` lets you plot parametric plots with the syntax

```
\addplot ({<expression for x}, {<expression for y>});
```

where the expressions for x and y are the right hand sides of your equations. In order to use `t` as the plotting variable, specify `variable=t`. Further, note that the trigonometric functions of `pgf` assume degrees as input by default, so you'll need to convert to radians manually, or specify `trig format plots=rad` to make radians the default. Finally, the parameters `a`, `b` `x_0`, `y_0` you can either replace with numbers, or use `declare function` as in the example below to define them.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
 a=1;
 b=1;
 x_0=0;
 y_0=0;
}]
\begin{axis}[axis equal,
axis lines=middle,
axis line style={->},
tick style={color=black},
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
trig format plots=rad
]

\addplot[samples=360, domain=0:2*pi, variable=t] 
({sin(t)*a^sin(t)+x_0}, {cos(t)*b^sin(t)+y_0});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want in 0 to 360 deg

Comment: @NikaShabashvili You had specified `domain=0:2*pi`, so I assumed you wanted to use radiians. If you want degrees, remove `trig format plots=rad`, and set `domain=0:360`.

Comment: thanks please you can help me with this graph? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632085/please-help-me-with-system-graph

Comment: @NikaShabashvili Isn't that exactly the same thing as this, just different expressions? Then I've already hjelped you, try applying this answer to that question.

Comment: When I tried the wrong schedule was drawn

Comment: @NikaShabashvili Then edit that question to include the code you tried, preferably along with a screenshot of your output and a sketch or description of the expected output. I'm not going to copy-paste this answer to another question, just replacing the expressions.

Comment: see i send errors

Comment: @NikaShabashvili Please *edit your other question*! Additional information should not be added as answer-posts, those are only for actual solutions to the problem. And add the code as text in addition, no one wants to type code off of a screenshot to test.

Comment: please send me a code

Comment: @NikaShabashvili No. You go to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632085/please-help-me-with-system-graph, edit that question to include the code of your attempt along with the screenshot, and describe what output you expect. There should be an *edit*'-link just below the question.

Comment: change it in this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632085/please-help-me-with-system-graph  ????

Comment: @NikaShabashvili Yes, that question. Click where it says *edit*, and paste the code in your screenshot there.